# deriving different clock signals from a system clock - frequency division & flags

Tags: verilog

I have been giving a specification to derive 10MHz,5MHz and 1MHz from a 20MHz system clock. I am also supposed to design posedge and negedge flags for all the three derived clocks.

I used a 4 bit counter which counted from 0-15 and the counter[0] gave me the 10MHz clock signal and the counter [1] gave me the 5MHz signal. I used another 5 bit counter which counted from 0-9. I made my 1MHz signal register toggle for 0-9 each count, which gave me the 1MHz clock signal.

Now I am struggling to design the posedge and negedge flags for all three of the clocks. I used a combination logic of posedge = a^!b; but I could get the flags for 10MHz and 5MHz but couldn't extract my 1MHz flags from this method.

I was suggested to use my two counters (4 bit and 5 bit) to easily design the flags for all three of them. Kindly suggest on this

my 1MHz snippet using the 5 bit counter

```
if(counter_1MHz == 5'd9)                                                    
begin
   counter_1MHz <= 5'd0;
   clk_1MHz_reg  <= ~clk_1MHz_reg;                                        
end 
else   
begin
   counter_1MHz <= counter_1MHz + 5'd1;
   clk_1MHz_reg  <= clk_1MHz_reg;             
end  
assign clk_1MHz = clk_1MHz_reg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posedge = a&!b where b is one cycle delayed from a:

```
always @(posedge clock)
   b <= a;

assign rising_edge = a & !b; // a is high but was low
```

Beware that a posedge from a 10 MHz clock derived from a 20MHz clock, is the 10MHz clock again. The negedge is the inverse clock. As such the requirement for those signals seems not very much thought out.

---

Building on your code:

```
reg  clk_1MHz_delay;
wire clk_1MHz_rising;
   always@(posedge clk_20MHz)
     clk_1MHz_delay <= clk_1MHz;
   assign clk_1MHz_rising = clk_1MHz & !clk_1MHz_delay;
```

Comment: You are right, for 10MHz its similar signal and the inverse  will give negedge flag. But for 5 Mhz the same method gives proper posedge and negedge flags. Its just I can't implement the same logic for 1MHz because of my snippet for 1MHz below :

Comment: if(counter_1MHz == 5'd9)                                  begin
       counter_1MHz <= 5'd0;
       clk_1MHz_reg  <= ~clk_1MHz_reg;            end 
       else                                                             begin
       counter_1MHz <= counter_1MHz + 5'd1;
       clk_1MHz_reg  <= clk_1MHz_reg;              end                                                                                                              assign clk_1MHz = clk_1MHz_reg;

Comment: The above code works for **any** signal. It assumes 'a' is synchronous to 'clock' and 'clock' is faster then 'a'. You should add your code to the question using the 'edit' button. Code must be separated by an empty line and preceded by four spaces.

Comment: I tried so hard to keep the format of my snippet, however it kept notifying that my code is several characters long, I had to make it compact and post

Comment: Thank you oldfart, I could implement the same idea for the 1MHz signal as well to get the edge flags.